# Jquery Mobile code disappears when adding media player

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

When I add a html 5 music player to my code that consists of a jquery mobile toolbar, the page goes blank and I cant get both the toolbar and the music player to appear. My code is HTML 5 validated and I have no idea how to get both the toolbar and music player to appear at the same time.

Here's my updated code with only the toolbar and toolbar buttons showing. ALso only part of the media player now shows nothing else is there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>This is my Music-Player</title>


 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">

 <link href="musicplayer/css/xemusicplayer.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="musicplayer/js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="musicplayer/js/jquery-xemusicplayer-1.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



</head>
<body>

<div id="player"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var songlist = new Array(3);
songlist[0] = new Object();
songlist[0].cover = "songs/Joe_Marson__The_Satisfied_Mind_-_09_-_Poor_St_John.jpg"
songlist[0].mp3 = "songs/Joe_Marson__The_Satisfied_Mind_-_09_-_Poor_St_John.mp3";
songlist[0].ogg = "songs/Joe_Marson__The_Satisfied_Mind_-_09_-_Poor_St_John.ogg"
songlist[0].title = "Poor St. John";
songlist[0].title_link = "http://freemusicarchive.org/music/Joe_Marson__The_Satisfied_Mind/netBloc_Vol_43_ANTIPETROMUSICABIOTIC/09_-_Joe_Marson__The_Satisfied_Mind_-_Poor_St_John";
songlist[0].artist = "Joe Marson & The Satisfied Mind";
songlist[1] = new Object();
songlist[1].cover = "songs/Chris_Zabriskie_-_01_-_The_Temperature_of_the_Air_on_the_Bow_of_the_Kaleetan.jpg"
songlist[1].mp3 = "songs/Chris_Zabriskie_-_01_-_The_Temperature_of_the_Air_on_the_Bow_of_the_Kaleetan.mp3";
songlist[1].ogg = "songs/Chris_Zabriskie_-_01_-_The_Temperature_of_the_Air_on_the_Bow_of_the_Kaleetan.ogg"
songlist[1].title = "The Temperature of the Air on the Bow of the Kaleetan";
songlist[1].title_link = "http://freemusicarchive.org/music/Chris_Zabriskie/Undercover_Vampire_Policeman/01_-_The_Temperature_of_the_Air_on_the_Bow_of_the_Kaleetan_1165";
songlist[1].artist = "Chris Zabriskie";
songlist[2] = new Object();
songlist[2].cover = "songs/Broke_For_Free_-_05_-_Something_Elated.jpg"
songlist[2].mp3 = "songs/Broke_For_Free_-_05_-_Something_Elated.mp3";
songlist[2].ogg = "songs/Broke_For_Free_-_05_-_Something_Elated.ogg"
songlist[2].title = "Something Elated";
songlist[2].title_link = "http://freemusicarchive.org/music/Broke_For_Free/Something_EP/Broke_For_Free_-_Something_EP_-_05_Something_Elated";
songlist[2].artist = "Broke For Free";

$("#player").xeMusicPlayer({songlist: songlist, theme: 2, mode: 2});
</script>



<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <div class="ui-grid-d">
            <div class="ui-block-a">test</div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <input type="search" name="search" id="search-basic" value="" placeholder="test" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c"><a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="alert" data-iconpos="left">test</a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-d"><a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="left">test</a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-e"><a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="left">test</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /grid-b -->
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding your header div in a page div:  `<div data-role="page">`

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <div class="ui-grid-d">
            <div class="ui-block-a">test</div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <input type="search" name="search" id="search-basic" value="" placeholder="test" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c"><a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="alert" data-iconpos="left">test</a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-d"><a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-u" data-iconpos="left">test</a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-e"><a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="left">test</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /grid-b -->
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="player"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: put player div in jQM content div.

Comment: That helped a little bit. Part of the media player is only appearing now and I can see the toolbar and toolbar buttons but not anything else. I updated my first post's code with what it is now.

Comment: what if you put the media player inside the page div too?

Comment: If I move #player right under div data-role="page">  then the one part of the media player I can see disappears (part of player is top center under black bar). See image for reference http://postimg.org/image/aeqc0w83b/

Comment: You should add a DIV with data-role="content" under the header DIV but inside the PAGE DIV and then place the player in there.  This would be the proper jQM setup for a page.  Also, you have 2 versions of jQuery referenced (1.8.3 and 2.0.0); you should only have one declared before jQuery Mobile and you should check that the music player is compatible with jQuery 1.8.3 or 1.9.x which work well with jQM.